# Catalog search index process error indexation process

Tags: catalog, search, reindex, opensearch

I did a new installation of Magento (2.4.6-p2) and did the data migration from Magento 1.
Everything seems to work, except the catalog pages, which give the following error on the frontend:

*Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\AdvancedSearch\Model\Client\ClientOptionsInterface in /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:121*

I have OpenSearch 2.11. In Magento backend the test is ok.
But I can't reindex the Catalog Search.

If I type:

*bin/magento indexer:reindex catalogsearch_fulltext*

the result is:

*Catalog Search index process error during indexation process:
Cannot instantiate interface Magento\AdvancedSearch\Model\Client\ClientOptionsInterface
[Exit 1]*

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

is it possible that the indexer has hung?
You may have already tried this but try:

1- `php bin/magento indexer:status`

2- `php bin/magento indexer:reset [TypeIndex]`

when index is reset:

3- `php bin/magento indexer:reindex [TypeIndex]`

4- `php bin/magento cache:flush`

As a last option, restart opensearch (?).

Tell me if it doesn't work for you and I'll think of something else.

Comment: I had already tried with these commands. But the problem was always the same.
After various vicissitudes, I have now solved the problem by simply enabling the "Magento_Elasticsearch" module.

Comment: Oh, and haven't you needed to disable opensearch safe mode???

Comment: No. Enabling the "Magento_Elasticsearch" module, Opensearch now is ok. I didn't do anything else.

Comment: I have a problem with opensearch today and the solution, after hours trying fix it was restart the server :D